# Had Christopher Tolkien ever publicly spoken about George R. R. Martin or his work?

Tags: christopher-tolkien, george-r-r-martin

Since J. R. R. Tolkien died in 1973, when George R. R. Martin was 24, I imagine he probably never heard of him. However, his son Christopher died only recently, so I was wondering whether there's any record of him saying anything about *A Song of Ice and Fire*, its author, or - most interestingly - its author's comment on Christopher's father work. For instance, there is famous/infamous quote of George speaking about Aragorn's "tax policy":

He also says in another interview that Tolkien should not have brought Gandalf back to life:

Did Christopher Tolkien ever comment on these things, or anything else regarding George or his work?

Comment: Nope, as GRRM says in that very interview, he missed his chance as a kid.

Comment: @Spencer To communicate with JRR Tolkien, not his son (Christopher).

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: @ibid Okay, thanks. If you know of no such instance, it's good enough for me. It's a shame though, I'd be interested in hearing his replies...

Comment: Funny about that second comment. Why did Martin bring any characters back to life if that’s how he felt about Gandalf?

Comment: @LoremIpsum Why is it incorrect?

Comment: @LoremIpsum Yes, but there is an implied action having occurred before (namely, Christopher's death). This is the standard way to speak about a deceased.

Comment: @LoremIpsum Yes, and that's why when you're talking about someone who is deceased, it is customary to use the pluperfect ("he'd done it [before he died]"), as opposed to when speaking about someone who is alive.

Comment: In any case, that's just the rule.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129039/discussion-between-loremipsum-and-wade).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Christopher Tolkien never commented on anything George R R Martin had said or written

While it is always difficult to prove a negative, Christopher Tolkien was a relatively quiet figure, especially in the last few decades of his life when George R R Martin made these statements.

Christopher's most public comments on works of Tolkien Criticism can be found in his *History of Middle-earth* series, which was published between 1983 and 1996.

> In Chapter 7 of his book *The Road to Middle-earth* Professor T. A. Shippey accepts that this is so ...
>
> In *The Complete Guide to Middle-earth* Robert Foster says ...
>
> Professor Randel Helms, in *Tolkien and the Silmarils* (p. 93), has stated ...
>
> And in an article entitled ‘The Text of *The Hobbit*: Putting Tolkien’s Notes in Order’ (English Studies in Canada, VII, 2, Summer 1981) Constance B. Hieatt concludes ...
> <sub>The Book of Lost Tales Part One - "Foreword"</sub>

> Barbara Strachey (*Journeys of Frodo*, maps 15-16) shows very unambiguously the ravine of Rivendell as the ravine of the tributary stream, Elrond's house being some mile and a half from its confluence with the Loudwater; while Karen Fonstad (*The Atlas of Middle-earth*, pp. 80, 101, etc.) likewise places Rivendell on the southerly stream - calling it (p. 127) the Bruinen.
> <sub>*The Return of the Shadow* - Chapter XI - "From Weathertop to the Ford" - note</sub>

The last of these books came out in 1996, the same year as the first A Song of Ice and Fire book, [and eighteen years before George R R Martin's tax policy line](https://www.rollingstone.com/culture/culture-news/george-r-r-martin-the-rolling-stone-interview-242487/).

None of Christopher Tolkien's publications since then had this type of commentary on other works, and he did *very few* public appearances and [only one press interview](https://web.archive.org/web/20140605092337/http://www.worldcrunch.com/culture-society/my-father-039-s-quot-eviscerated-quot-work-son-of-hobbit-scribe-j.r.r.-tolkien-finally-speaks-out/hobbit-silmarillion-lord-of-rings/c3s10299/).

He continued to review and comment on such things through private correspondence ([see his c.2006 remarks here on Douglas Charles Kane's *Arda Reconstructed*](https://www.thehalloffire.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=2250&sid=8cd1494eb408ae53eef603baf6be5ec6)) while still alive, and it is *possible* that he'd seen and/or privately commented on George R.R. Martin, but he never did so publicly.

Comment: maybe worth noting, (I'm sure you know this) - CT died in 2020. The tense used in your answer could imply that he's still around and the answer may change if he decided to comment later :)

Comment: Great answer. That's too bad though. I don't imagine that anyone else with a high status in the Tolkien estate said anything on the subject?

Comment: @NKCampbell - I tightened up some of the tense.

Comment: @Wade - None that I know of. Christopher was the public (non-legal) face of the Estate, and it's not really the type for any of them to be making a public response to something a different author said in an interview. You can find plenty of discussion on various Tolkien webforums from the time though.